# Javascript regex: ignore every letter after backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to retrieve the free variables in a lambda expression.
For example

```
\z.\x.(xy)
```

, where "\" stand for the Lambda symbol: through a regex, I need to get all the letters which don't follow a backslash.
In my example, the free variables would be

```
{y}
```

since "y" is the only variable not bounded to "\".
How could I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need that for? Why not parse the lambda expression into an AST, and compute free variables on that?

Comment: Easiest way is probably to retrieve all the "escaped" letters, then match all the letters that you haven't retrieved at the first pass. I would like to see a one regex solution though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/\\(\w+)/g` and iterate with `exec` :

```
var r = /\\(\w+)/g, m,
    s = "\\z.\\x.(xy)";
while (m = r.exec(s)) console.log(m[1]);
```

It logs `"z"` then `"x"`.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/moxiq/1/edit)

---

**To answer the new question:**

To get the names *not* following a `\`, you may use `/([^\\]|^)(\w+)/g` (and use the second capturing group which is the third element in the returned array).

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/moxiq/2/edit)

Comment: Sorry dude, i realized that there's a simpler way to get what I need: i updated the question, and I need the letters which don't follow a backslash, i.e. (y) :)
Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Simpler? Not with regex! You could run two regexes: one to detect all variables and this one, put all the results into two sets, and apply a set difference operation.

Comment: @elmazzun: But `x` (in `(xy)`) doesn't follow a backslash either?

Comment: @dystroy, the second solution returns me ["xy"], but x is after a backslash in the formula above: the free variables are those which don't follow immediately a backslash.
So, the output should be only "y".

Comment: @elmazzun I now understand what you want 1) it's probably not possible with a regex engine without back reference 2) it's a bad idea anyway to try to do all this in a regex, you should use/write a parser instead.

Comment: Thank you, you've been very patient.
At least, now I know what not to do.